# How To Get a Key/Value from Associative Array with JQuery

Tags: jquery, associative-array, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am setting up an associative array for a Kendo DropDownList. The object returns 33 as the val(). I want to retrieve the name associated with Id 33. How do I assign ProjName the Name key where Id=33?

HTML output from the Kendo control:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    MyJS.Project.Create.Initialize('[{"$id":"1","Id":32,"Name":"Test Project"},{"$id":"2","Id":33,"Name":"Simple Project"}]');
</script>
```

Kendo DropDownList:

```
<input id="lstProject" class="span8"  data-bind="kendoDropDownList:{data:Projects, value: Project, dataTextField: 'Name', dataValueField: 'Id',optionLabel: 'Select Project' }"/>
```

Assigning associative array to variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ProjName = $("#lstProject").val();
    alert(ProjName);
</script>
```

Comment: It might help you (and us) understand what's going on if you look at what html your first and second code snippets generate.

Comment: The code for Kendo DropDownList generates the HTML output (the first snippet of code).

Comment: The alert box shows 33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this -

```
 $val = ('#lstProject').val();
 $name = $('[value="'+$val+'"]').attr('name');
```

Comment: Since var ProjName = $("#lstProject").val(); returns 33, would the line be:
var msgHeader = $("#CPRProject").val().attr('name');

Comment: i am not sure about your code as i dont know what is #CPRProject

Comment: I copied it from another sample and did not make all of the variable changes. It should have been #lstProject.